# selenium python how to wait for presence individual elements after table found

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I wait for the presence of headers of a table.

```
headers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='react-table']/thead/tr/th/span")))
```

headers is then a python list of webelements.

However when I iterate over that list with a variable **h** and I use `h.text`, a stale element reference exception is thrown.

I believe I need to wait explicitly on the elements making up the list one by one.

Is there a way to call `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located....)` given that I have the webelements?

Answer (score 0):

I think unless you can specifically select to wait on the last row of the table (ie you'd need to know what the last table is in advance), the short answer is not in a good way. And even then, that would not prevent the table from rerendering.

If a StaleElementReferenceException is being thrown, that means that the DOM has rerendered the table, which can happen depending on the website. Sometimes even a few times. Selenium had access to an element, but once the element rerenders, the old element no longer exists, and the new element must be selected (even if visually they are exactly the same).

There are a few ways around this. One is to use a different library such as Playwright (rerendering of tables doesn't throw StaleElementReferenceExceptions as a feature of this library). Another is to put a timer in and just set the delay high enough that all rerendering is complete (but this is not optimal, because sometimes websites are slower than you expect). Another is to attempt your code for X times in a loop with some delay, wrapped in a try except that will catch StaleElementReferenceException s (really though, same problem as the previous solution).

Really, Playwright is the fix for this (unless you're okay with sometimes erroring out due to time delays being too short), and Selenium just doesn't have a good pattern imo for dealing with pages using javascript frameworks like React that might rerender elements in a page multiple times.

Comment: I ended using beautiful soup to catch the rendering at a instant and process the table souped. that worked. but good to know about Playwright